# Loading lots of data into MySQL without SSH access?

Tags: php, mysql, ssh

I wanted to connect to my server via ssh and run a php script to enter some data into the MySQL databases.
   I couldn't do this because I didn't have ssh access.

So instead I'm just going to put a php script into one of my web pages and then put the data in the same folder and then run the php by loading the browser

this seems like a really wierd way to enter data into a database?

but is it ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a PHP script to execute an SQL script should not be a problem (but be sure to delete both afterwards, just so you don't leave an unvalidated/regulated passage into your database out there).

If your webhost provides a MySQL Admin interface (often phpMyAdmin), you should be able to access that through their Control Panel (often called "cPanel" or "Plesk"). You should be able to upload and execute an SQL file through that interface without installing anything else.

Failing that, you should be able to install [Adminer](http://www.adminer.org/), which is a cutdown version of phpMyAdmin which you can then upload to your server and access through a web browser to, again, upload or copy-and-paste your SQL script into.

Comment: maybe i just need to use the mysql LOAD DATA INFILE   , god computer programming is so hard!!

Comment: You cannot use LOAD DATA INFILE if your data needs to be preprocessed.

Comment: looks like phpmyadmin already has some nice functions to import CSV file data... i should have looked before i asked this question

Answer (score 1):

So you are basically rebuilding [phpMyAdmin's](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/) behaviour. I would just install phpMyAdmin, but if your php script is protected (.htaccess or similar), then this should be no problem. Look out for [timeouts](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php).

Comment: maybe i need to look into what i can do with phpmyadmin, i thought it could only be used for MYSQL statements, is this not the case?

Comment: In your question you are talking about entering data into MySQL databases?

Comment: You insert data into MySQL databases with MySQL statements. That's what phpMyAdmin is for.

Comment: the data needs to be worked on a little before i put it in, i was thinking of doing that in php and also using php mysql functions to write to the database

Comment: If your data needs pre processing, then you have to use a script to update. That wasn't clear from your question, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

A good tool for working with MySQL db is [Workbench](http://wb.mysql.com/), but you must have remote access to your db...